# Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1 (through reference chain: ...->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Tags: java, xml, jackson, aiml, xmlmapper

I'm using XMLMapper to deserialize AIML code (mostly the same as XML) and got this problem when I mix text and tags under the same tag. Example:

```
<set name="setVar">
  <srai>FUNCTION1</srai>
  <srai>FUNCTION2<star index="1"/></srai>
</set>
```

My java classes definition are:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "set")
public class Set {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "name")
    public String name;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "srai")
    public List<Srai> srais;

    public Set() {
    }

    public Set(String name, List<Srai> srais) {
        this.name = name;
        this.srais = srais;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Srai> getSrais() {
        return srais;
    }

    public void setSrais(List<Srai> srais) {
        this.srais = srais;
    }
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "srai")
public class Srai {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "star")
    public List<Star> stars;
    @JacksonXmlText
    public String text;
    
    public Srai() {}
    
    public Srai(String text, List<Star> stars) {
        this.text = text;
        this.stars = stars;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public List<Star> getStars() {
        return stars;
    }

    public void setStars(List<Star> stars) {
        this.stars = stars;
    }
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "star")
public class Star {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public int index;
    
    public Star() {
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

If I try to deserialize code in which there are only text or only *stars* into the *srai*, everything works perfect, the problem appears when I mix text and tags.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it upgrading my jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotation and jackson-dataformat-xml to the version 2.12.1 as tnci suggested [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/203).

**To do this, just change their version into the pom.xml to 2.12.1 or later versions.**

Then I created a new property into the *star* class:

```java
@JacksonXmlText
public String text;
```

This way, when there is text before or between xml tags, it will be saved in this property on a *star* object. If the text is after all xml tags, there will appear this problem:

```
Unexpected end-of-input when trying read value of type `**root-agent-class**`
```

So the problem persists but now it's much better since we can read some text+tags code.